# Laptop overheating after switching from windows to xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, cpu, overheating

I recently switched from windows to xubuntu, just because i was getting bored of the same UI.

Whenever i do light stuff such as watching YouTube videos, my fans are much louder than when i had windows. I installed Psensor and found out my CPU is running at 70 C while watching youtube videos(normally at 55/60 C *with windows*).

Specs: Lenovo g580:
-i3-2348m
-8gb ddr3 ram
-gt635m

I tried searching around and found basically nothing, any help is appreciated.

[Top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE8RA.png)

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I installed bumblebee and that seemed to do the trick, my laptop now runs just like it used to do in windows.

A new problem arose, bumblebee somehow messed with my already existing drivers and now i got a ugly line down my screen whenever something moves fairly fast. will reinstalling the Nvidia Driver mess with bumblebee or not?

Answer (score 2):

Your `top` listing indicates that your browser (Chromium) seems to be the culprit, eating a lot of CPU.

Try a few different browsers: Firefox, Opera, Chrome, etc. and see if they give you better results.

Comment: [new top thing](https://imgur.com/eCGWFw3) here is the new top thing, the temps are still not as good as the windows ones but are a lot better

Comment: now the temps are around 63c from 70c. still not as good as the windows temps which were around above 50 but under 60

Answer (score 0):

I would also attempt different browsers, as user535733 indicates. You could for instance try the actual chrome browser from the google repo: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-google-chrome-ubuntu-18-04-lts

But you might try some of the laptop-related power packages as well, specifically powertop and tlp

Powertop (run as `sudo powertop` while on battery) will tell you exactly what is causing the machine to use power and also allow you to tweak power modes of various hardware components to use less. This will extend your battery life and should reduce temperatures as well.